# asp.net -- store checkbox information for session

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, viewbag

I have a list of items, that a user can check:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < items[].Length - 1; i++)
{
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="items-link">Selected Items</a>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" data="@item" class="items-checkbox" />
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

When a user checks an item, the link url is updated to include that item via javascript:

```
var url = "/checked-items/?";

for (var i = 0; i < itemsThatAreChecked.length; i++) {
    url += "item=" + itemsThatAreChecked[i] + (i == itemsThatAreChecked.length - 1 ? "" : "&");
}

$(".items-link").attr("href", url);
```

However, I would like to expand this functionality so that the items that a user has selected are available throughout their session. Would ViewBag be the appropriate choice for storing this information? Can the information be updated via javascript (i.e. when the item is checked, add it to the list, and when it is unchecked, remove it from the list)

Comment: Can you show us the JS you have?

Answer (score 0):

All you would need to do is to invoke a function when the user clicks one of the items in the list to update 
    itemsThatAreChecked[]
Then when they click Submit another JS function can build the URL with the items that are checked.

Comment: itemsThatAreChecked[] is only available to one view. If the user goes to another page, this information is lost. I am trying to store the information for the entire user session, so that I can re-access it during later page views

Comment: That is a tough one then.  If you are using HTML5 you can store the information locally on the client to retrieve by each page.  I suggest you look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TempData instead of ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do is to invoke a function when user clicks one of the items in the list to update itemsThatAreChecked[] Then when they click Submit another JS function can build the URL with the items that are checked.